# Selenium Automation - Cucumber and JUnit - No public static parameters method

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

Hi community: Trying to integrate Cucumber with JUnit, I have the next class.

```
import cl.cukes.ParameterizedRunnerFactory;
import cl.test.AutomatedWebTest;
import cl.util.report.Report;
import cucumber.annotation.en.Given;
import cucumber.annotation.en.Then;
import cucumber.annotation.en.When;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.UseParametersRunnerFactory;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.parameterized.TestWithParameters;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

//JAVA

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@UseParametersRunnerFactory(ParameterizedRunnerFactory.class)
public class CucumberStepDefs extends AutomatedWebTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 0)
    public String user;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(value = 1)
    public String pass;


   public static class CucumberRunnerFactor extends ParameterizedRunnerFactory {

       public Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(TestWithParameters test)
               throws InitializationError {
           try {
               return new Cucumber(test.getTestClass().getJavaClass());
           } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new InitializationError(e);
           }
       }
    }
    @Given("^Enter to the QA URL environment")
    public void Login() throws Exception {

        baseUrl = "http://www.miprivado.cl/";
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl + "ucachaca/test.htm");
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame("frmbody");
    }

    @When("^Fields Username y Passwordare displayed so enter parameters$")
    public void UsuarioPass() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbTELLUSERID")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbTELLUSERID")).sendKeys(user);
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbUSERPASSW")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("TxbUSERPASSW")).sendKeys(pass);


        screenshot.take(this, driver, "LoginR C01");
        driver.findElement(By.id("BtnSubmit")).click();
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame("frmwebteller");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Then("^User gets into the system and do Logout Logout$")
    public void Logout() throws Exception {
        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C02");

        driver.switchTo ().defaultContent ();
        driver.switchTo ().frame ("frmbody").switchTo ().frame ("menu"); 

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b")).click();
        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C03");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Off")).click();
        screenshot.take (this, driver, "LoginR C04");

        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

The ParameterizedRunnerFactory is the next:

```
import org.junit.runner.Runner;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.parameterized.ParametersRunnerFactory;
import org.junit.runners.parameterized.TestWithParameters;

/**
 *
 */
public class ParameterizedRunnerFactory implements ParametersRunnerFactory {
    @Override
    public Runner createRunnerForTestWithParameters(TestWithParameters test) throws InitializationError {
        return new ParameterizedRunner(test);
    }
}
```

The parameterized Runner class is the next:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runners.model.*;
import org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters;
import org.junit.runners.parameterized.TestWithParameters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ParameterizedRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters {
        public ParameterizedRunner(TestWithParameters test) throws InitializationError {
            super(test);
        }

        // workaround for: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/issues/1046
        private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, TestClass> testClasses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        @Override
        protected TestClass createTestClass(Class<?> clazz) {
            TestClass testClass = testClasses.get(clazz);
            if (testClass == null) {
                testClasses.put(clazz, testClass = new TestClass(clazz));
            }
            return testClass;
        }

        // playing whack-a-mole with new TLAB allocations by re-defining with{Befores,Afters}...

        @Override
        protected Statement withBefores(FrameworkMethod method, Object target, Statement statement) {
            List<FrameworkMethod> list = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(Before.class);
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return statement;
            }
            return new BeforesStatement(target, statement, list);
        }

        @Override
        protected Statement withAfters(FrameworkMethod method, Object target, Statement statement) {
            List<FrameworkMethod> list = getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(After.class);
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return statement;
            }
            return new AftersStatement(target, statement, list);
        }

        private static final class BeforesStatement extends Statement {
            private static final Object[] EMPTY_ARGS = new Object[0];
            private final Object target;
            private final Statement statement;
            private final List<FrameworkMethod> list;

            BeforesStatement(Object target, Statement statement, List<FrameworkMethod> list) {
                this.target = target;
                this.statement = statement;
                this.list = list;
            }

            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                // (1) Avoid ImmutableCollections#iterator()
                for (int i = 0, size = list.size(); i < size; ++i) {
                    list.get(i).invokeExplosively(target, EMPTY_ARGS);
                }
                statement.evaluate();
            }
        }

        private static final class AftersStatement extends Statement {
            private static final Object[] EMPTY_ARGS = new Object[0];
            private final Object target;
            private final Statement statement;
            private final List<FrameworkMethod> list;

            AftersStatement(Object target, Statement statement, List<FrameworkMethod> list) {
                this.target = target;
                this.statement = statement;
                this.list = list;
            }

            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                // (2) Lazily create ArrayList
                ArrayList<Throwable> throwables = null;
                try {
                    statement.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    throwables = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
                    throwables.add(e);
                } finally {
                    for (int i = 0, size = list.size(); i < size; ++i) {
                        try {
                            list.get(i).invokeExplosively(target, EMPTY_ARGS);
                        } catch (Throwable e) {
                            if (throwables == null) {
                                throwables = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
                            }
                            throwables.add(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (throwables != null) {
                    MultipleFailureException.assertEmpty(throwables);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Cucumber Runner Test class is the next:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features={"//src/features/Login.feature"}
                 ,format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"}
                 ,glue = {"cucumber.CucumberStepDefs"}
)
/*@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        CucumberStepDefs.class,
})*/

public class CucumberRunnerTest {

}
```

When I run my CucumberStepDefs, it displays the next issue on IntelliJ:

```
java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class cl.cucumber.CucumberStepDefs
```

All the classes don't show error, but I'm not able to run this class.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Why did u add the Parametrized Runner to the stepdefinition class? You just need to add the Cucumber runner to integrate with junit as you have done with the last class.

Comment: If I change the //@RunWith(Parameterized.class) with the @RunWith(Cucumber.class), It displays the next message: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 

Classes annotated with @RunWith(Cucumber.class) must not define any
Step Definition or Hook methods. Their sole purpose is to serve as
an entry point for JUnit. Step Definitions and Hooks should be defined
in their own classes. This allows them to be reused across features.
Offending class: class cl.cucumber.CucumberStepDefs

Comment: What is the need for any junit class on a stepdefinition class? The stepdefinition code will be automatically found by the cucumber framework, using the glue option in the cucumberoptions annotation of the runner class. You should pass the parameters values in the feature file using the scenariooutline, if you want to repeat a scenario with multiple values.

Comment: I'm new in this with Cucumber. The parameterized parameters are used for extract the content of the txt files in another package. I'm trying to do the interaction between JUnit (Implemented here) and Cucumber. How could I do the scenariooutline in the feature class?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-scenario-outline

Comment: Thanks for the link and your help, Grasshopper. Acording your experience, integrating Cucumber and JUnit is not a good idea. I will refact my class only using Cucumber, but in my job it is used the JUnit framework and there are a lot of classes with that notation. Thanks again.

Comment: When you use the RunWith(Cucumber.class), you are using the Cucumber runner which is a specialized junit runner. The integration is automatic. Check out the source code of this class, it extends the ParentRunner of junit. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/junit/src/main/java/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to mix JUnit with Maven:

The best answer were done by Grasshopper:

1.- Create the Feature file.

2.- Use Scenario Outline and put the data in Examples section.

3.- Use a runner like next:

```
    @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resource/features"},
                 glue={"stepdefs"},
                 monochrome = true,
                 tags = {"~@Ignore"},
                 plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                           "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                           "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt",
                           "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"}
)
public class TestRunner extends ExtendedTestNGRunner{
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

And run the Feature.

Thanks a lot, Grasshopper!!!

Comment: Will this support Parallel runners as well?